# Search function within another search function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for formula which could search for various characters in multiple cells.
This is my table example:

```
        A
1 Oikes - Simon
2 Ksenia & Igor
3 Dan + Bea
...
```

And I want to search for "-","&","+" characters. I thought this formula could work but it doesnt:

```
=SEARCH("-";SEARCH("&";A2;1);1)
```

Is Search within Search even possible? If not, what formula should I use? Thank you.

Comment: You can't search in this way because your first search formula will return a number and second search will fail to search `-` to that returned number. What is your end goal? What output you expect from cell `A2`?

Comment: @Harun24HR From A2 cell I expect output: 7. From A3 output: 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option,

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-FIND({"&","-"},A1))
```

Comment: Clever use of `LOOKUP()`.

Comment: @bosco_yip Doesnt work for. I'm getting invalid within find func - find_text for {"&","-"}

Comment: Try to change the formula comma "," to semi-colon ";" for suit your country setting.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(FIND({"&","-","+"},A1),""))
```

This way you won't need to nest multiple `FIND()` or `SEARCH()`, but on the downside it's an array formula which would need CSE-entering in pre-365 versions of Excel unless you nest an extra `INDEX()`, eg: `=MIN(INDEX(IFERROR(FIND({"&","-","+"},A1),""),))`

Obviously change comma to semi-colon as per your locale requires.